# Formulating English statements as a set of First Order Logic statements

Tags: prolog, first-order-logic

I'm currently learning FOL and have a number of English statements that I'm trying to formulate into FOL statements.

I have the English statements as well as my FOL attempts at each. I'm just wondering if there's anybody who can let me know if and where I might have gone wrong on them, thanks.

### ENGLISH STATEMENTS

1. A tall  man can reach a high hook.
2. A small man can reach a low hook.
3. The high hook is free.
4. A man will hang his coat if there is a coat hook free and the man can reach that coat hook.
5. Paul is a tall man.
6. John is a short man.
7. Who can hang their coat on what hook?

### FIRST-ORDER LOGIC STATEMENT ATTEMPTS

1. ∀x man(X, tall) -> reach_hook(X, high_hook).
2. ∀x man(X, small) -> reach_hook(X, low_hook).
3. free(high_hook).
4. ∀x,y free(X) ^ reach_hook(Y,X) -> hang_coat(Y, X).
5. man(paul,tall).
6. man(john, short).
7. ?- hang_coat(X,Y).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Prolog when you say FOL. They are not the same thing.

General comments: Prolog variables are implicitly universally (all) quantified, so you do not need the ∀ quantifier, which is why Prolog does not have it. Existential quantifier is written X^ as in

```
X^(man(X), tall(X))
```

but can only be used in bodies of predicates. If you want to say something like "there is a tall man" you would need to use an atom to represent him, as in

```
tall(xyzzy001).
man(xyzzy001).
```

So, your examples. In #1 & #2 both the man and the hook are clearly universally quantified, but you use an atom for the hook (or the two hooks). Also `man/2` and `reach_hook/1` seem ad-hoc. Do all men have exactly one property? What is so special about reaching hooks as opposed to shelves, ledges, door handles... Perhaps something like the following might be better.

```
reach(X,Y) :- man(X), tall(X), hook(Y), high(Y).
reach(X,Y) :- man(X), small(X), hook(Y), low(Y).
```

(Changed to make it valid syntax.)

In #3 you are appropriately using an atom, but to keep it consistent with the previous clauses, we might instead say

```
hook(xyzzy002).
high(xyzzy002).
free(xyzzy002).
```

Examples #5 and #6 are similar. In #4 you seem to have simplified away the specification of the hook as a "coat hook", which is probably not important, and your predicates could be more general, like

```
hang(X,Z,Y) :- man(X), hook(Y), coat(Z), reach(X,Y), free(Y).
```

(Changed to make it valid syntax.)

And assuming this formalisation and a populated database, question #7 can be stated as

```
?- hang(X,Z,Y), coat(Z), owns(X,Z).
```

And `owns/2` should probably be included in #4 also.